# 2013 Macbook Air not showing 1440p Option on External Display

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, displayport, hdmi

I have a mid 2013 Macbook Air with the Intel HD 5000 graphics chip. I recently purchased a 27" Acer K272HULbmiidp 1440p (2560x1440) monitor that just arrived today. I connected it via a mini displayport to HDMI cable, and was immediately greeted with awful graphics that didn't fit. Turns out its a common issue with external displays on macs, which assume settings for a TV not a monitor. Basically, I fixed it by [using a Ruby script to force RGB mode](https://gist.github.com/SalGnt/6184421) onto the monitor. So that's all good now.

The issue is I can't seem to get the 2560x1440 option on the external display, it will only show 1920x1080. I have heard the mini displayport to display port cable will allow my computer to run an external monitor in 1440p. Is this true? Please suggest what I can do to get the external display running in 1440p. Thank you so much guys.

Comment: Which specific DP to HDMI adapter are you using? The best I've seen support a maximum resolution of 1920 x 1080p @60Hz and not 1440p at any refresh rate.

Comment: if you go to the ColorSync utility in the utility folder and look what profile is been used ?

Comment: @bmike I was using a Belkin mini DisplayPort to HDMI: http://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-F2CD044/?ref=CJ // I ordered a mini Displayport to displayport cable on Amazon for $9. Will that fix the issue?

Comment: I ended up using miniDP -> DP on both my 1440p monitors to get them working happily. Even though the MacBook may be HDMI 1.4, the cable might not be.

Comment: That's awesome! Would you want to put that all in the answer as the solution? I'm sure it will help lots of people to see that this question has a real, check approved answer.

Comment: I received my mini displayport to displayport cable and am trying that out now. Once plugged in, My macbook cursor started to lag heavily. I fixed it by putting it in closed lid position. It worked, and then I clicked on 2560x1440 res and suddenly the whole thing went black, and said no input. Now I can't see anything on the display. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Did you check if you have a Display Port on the monitor apart the HDMI? 
I had the same issue with my late 2012 mac mini, and I had to buy a mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort to use the 1440p resolution

Answer (score 0):

We are using an inexpensive Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable between newer (2013) MacBook Pros and the Dell U2713HM monitor, and getting the full 2560 x 1440 at 60 Hz.  Our older MBPs need the more expensive Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter from Apple.

Comment: I received my mini displayport to displayport cable and am trying that out now. Once plugged in, My macbook cursor started to lag heavily. I fixed it by putting it in closed lid position. It worked, and then I clicked on 2560x1440 res and suddenly the whole thing went black, and said no input. Now I can't see anything on the display. Any help?

Comment: Not sure, could be an unsupported combination of settings?  Assuming you can start the Mac up fresh (disconnected from the monitor), you could try the free "Display Menu" app from the app store.  It will let you choose from all the supported display options

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's true, and it's not related or limited to Macs, but more of a hardware limitation.

It is my understanding that similar to how normal 29,99 DVI adapters only support 1920x1200 max, and you have to go to 99,99 dual-link DVI if you want higher resolution, the HDMI through these cheaper adapters is likewise limited to a single link, and thus you can't do full 1440p.

Also, see [why login screen has a 2-second delay with external monitor?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97305/why-login-screen-has-a-2-second-delay-with-external-monitor/105127#105127) in order to select a proper mDP to DP cable.